# Power BI and Python not aligned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to power BI but not new to python / pandas. What about power BI changes the values passed to the python script editor and how do I account for it in my scripting / setup in Power BI?

If I have to manually grab excel files in power BI it somewhat defeats the purpose of using it at all.

Here is the scenario: I created a .groupby() pivot table and plotted it in python. I get the graph I expected. When I move the script over to the power BI python script editor I get a clearly incorrect graph. It only has 3 data points and it looks like it is doing a table sum rather than a group by average? The values go out to 1E6

To clarify the incorrect graph is generated when I use the dataframe created by Power BI after selecting the fields you want access to. The core data source is exactly the same. I am able to recreate the original correct graph if I grab the original CSV.

Here is a picture of the graph power BI creates.

[image]

Here is something close to what I expect

[image]

I am using the following code in both python and the Power BI python script editor. Th

```
#The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

#dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Color, ValueB, Value_A, ID, StepTime, Bucket)
#dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

#Paste or type your script code here:
#assumptions: all returned email columns are named
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

df1 = dataset  # Power BI specific and returns the funky graph
df1 = pd.read_excel # Works in both power BI and Python


base = 100
print(df1.head())
df1['Value_A'] = df1['Value_A'].round(0).astype('Int64')
df1['Buckets'] = (df1['Value_A']/base).round(0)*base
df1['Buckets'] = df1['Buckets'].round(0).astype('Int64')

df2 = df1.groupby(['ID','Buckets'])['ValueB'].mean().reset_index()

df2 = df2.loc[df2['Buckets'] > 5]
group_19 = df2.loc[df2['ID'] == 19]
group_67 = df2.loc[df2['ID'] == 67]
group_69 = df2.loc[df2['ID'] == 69]


#Plotting
plt.scatter(group_19['Buckets'], group_19['ValueB'],c = 'blue')
plt.plot(group_19['Buckets'],group_19['ValueB'],ls='-',marker = 'o', c = 'blue')

plt.scatter(group_67['Buckets'], group_67['ValueB'],c = 'green')
plt.plot(group_67['Buckets'],group_67['ValueB'],ls='-',marker = 'o', c = 'green')

plt.scatter(group_69['Buckets'], group_69['ValueB'],c = 'red')
plt.plot(group_69['Buckets'],group_69['ValueB'],ls='-',marker = 'o', c = 'red')



plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than i thought. Power BI automatically summarizes the data when you load it in. I have to manually choose "Do not Summarize" in order to get the correct raw data.